# Replace one tire 205/75r15 with a 215/75r15 tire

Tags: tires

I have an old truck Dodge Dakota I don’t drive very often. One of the tires,the front passenger side tire,  needs to be replaced. All tires are 205/75r15. Is it OK to replace the one tire,front passenger tire, with a 215/75r15 size. The other 3 would still be 205/75r15

Answer (score 1):

In an emergency it would be OK but you should not do this over the long-term.

The problem is that the different sizes may affect steering, handling, and especially braking performance.  If you have ABS that could be adversely affected too.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I’ll just keep it as a spare. I appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Comment: If put onto the drive axle, it can also cause issues with the differential. If a 4x4, could negatively affect the transfer case.